# How to install AMD Radeon 570 Driver

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, radeon, 23.10

How to install Drivers for Linux Ubuntu 23.10? I am struggling to install it and don't know the right terminal commands to it.

When I added this in:

```
xrandr
```

It given me back this exact error message here:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

And then this message detail right here:

```
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

Comment: Do you have Muon Package Manager? I know how to install graphic drivers that way.

Comment: No i don't... Can you tell me a way to install this Muon Package Manager? i am lost and don't know how to do that.

Comment: It's actually $ sudo apt install muon

Comment: You can also install Muon with Discover. What GUI are you using? Is it by chance KDE Plasma? When you get Muon installed, and if your system supports that driver, I will give you step by step if you need it.